Git works only in eclipse
I cannot figure out why Git works in eclipse, but doesn't work in git bash. The repository is a gitlab repository and I access through username and access token. If I try to pull, while in eclipse I got the response I expect:

in git bash console, when I type "git pull", I obtain
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.xxxx.it/xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Here's the list of my git configurations:
$ git config --list
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=true
core.editor="C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
pull.rebase=false
credential.helper=manager
credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath=true
init.defaultbranch=master
user.name=giovanni.difronzo
user.email=giovanni.difronzo@xxxx.it
http.sslbackend=schannel
http.sslverify=false
pack.deltacachesize=2047m
pack.packsizelimit=2047m
pack.windowmemory=2047m
pack.window=1
core.packedgitlimit=512m
core.packedgitwindowsize=512m
core.compression=0
difftool.sourcetree.cmd=''
mergetool.sourcetree.cmd=''
mergetool.sourcetree.trustexitcode=true
credential.helper=manager
core.symlinks=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://gitlab.xxxxx.it/xxxx/xxxx/xxxxx.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.master.rebase=false
branch.develop.remote=origin
branch.develop.merge=refs/heads/develop
branch.develop.rebase=false

Can someone help me? Maybe git from git bash doesn't read the access token?
Thank you in advance

I must be connected to the VPN to get the access to the repositories

It’s better to edit the question instead of adding more information here in the comments.

Issue solved! I had to set the vpn proxy in the git configuration:
git config --global http.proxy http://xxx.xx.xx:xxx

Then I've entered gitlab's username and personal access token and it works! In eclipse I could enter username and personal access token even without the proxy set. I don't know why.
